# how do i replace a line in a text file using variables? python

Tags: python-3.x, replace

```
import fileinput, csv

mark = input("mark:")

username = input("username:")

with open("marksh.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if username in line:
            username, markeasy, markmedium , markhard = line.strip().split("\t")
            with open("marksh.txt", "a")as f:
                f.write(username + "    " + mark + "    " + markmedium+ "    " + markhard)

with open("marksh.txt","r") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

    finduser = input("username:")

    for line in lines:
        if finduser in line:
            username, markeasy, markmedium , markhard = line.strip().split("\t")
            print((username) + (markeasy))
```

I want the code to be able to change say markeasy with mark

e.g. test    5    6   7

i want it so that the file will change to

test    8    6    7

i know how to do it with strings but i need it to work with variables.